# Implementation of a Hanning filter

Tags: signal-processing

I'm implementing a package for in-house signal processing.

I wrote here a quite trivial function implementing a Hanning windowing of the signal.

```
HanningFilter[signal_List] := Module[{length},
   length = Length[signal];
   Table[signal[[k]] 2 Sin[π k/length]^2, {k, 1, length}]
];
```

I know there is a `HannWindow[x]` built-in function that can be use. However the question I have can be applied to other filters as well:

> What is the most performant implementation of such a function?

Probably the use of a `Table[]` is not optimal.

Comment: von Hann. Not Hanning.

Comment: In this case they are synonyms.

Comment: In the same sense that Cedring is a synonym for your own name...

Comment: Except that nobody calls me Cedring while Hanning is commonly used (even if the origin is doubtful: Hann / Hamming => Hanning).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
HanningFilter[signal_List] := 
   With[{len = Length[signal]}, 2 signal Sin[Pi Range[len]/len]^2]
```

Sin, Times,Power are Listable,that means

```
Attributes /@ {Sin, Times, Power}
Sin[{a, b}]
{a, b}^2
{a, b} {c, d}
(*{{Listable,NumericFunction,Protected},{Flat,Listable,
     NumericFunction,OneIdentity,Orderless,Protected},
     {Listable, NumericFunction, OneIdentity, Protected}}*)
(*{Sin[a],Sin[b]}*)
(*{a^2, b^2}*)
(*{a c,b d}*)
```

Comment: Could I suggest adding `prec = Max[Precision[signal], MachinePrecision]` and using something like `len = SetPrecision[Length[signal], prec]` instead, in combination with `Range[SetPrecision[1, prec], len]`? This way `Range` produces, and `Sin` sees, a list of inexact numbers, which will be faster than using rationals, especially for a `MachinePrecision` signal.